# Nonlinear optimization for minimizing matrix norm

Tags: optimization

Suppose that $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a nonlinear matrix function of $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. We may assume that $A(x)$ is continuously differentiable. Are there any good ways to estimate $\mathrm{argmin}_{x} \|A(x)\|_2$? Also assume that due to some growth properties of the function $A(x)$, this minimizer can only be achieved within a known compact set. There are well known methods when $A(x)$ is linear with respect to $x$, but I don't have that linearity here.

I have tried to implement a few quasi-Newton methods with varying success, and I've also tried MATLAB's `fminunc` command with reasonable success (stabilizing around local minima is a problem). Unfortunately I'm relatively unfamiliar with the literature on these things (and the literature is quite vast). Are there any general approaches anybody could suggest?

Comment: The answer will probably depend more on the form of $A$ than the fact that you seek its 2-norm minimizer. Can you say more about the form of $A$?

Comment: Very generally, $A = B(x)^{-1} C(x)$, where $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ have entries that are analytic functions of $x$, and $B(x)$ has a bounded inverse. So there's not too much structure here. I'd like to know what are some reliable general methods, I suppose. One can easily reformulate this as minimizing the maximum eigenvalue of a symmetric positive definite matrix, but again the entries will not have much structure.

Comment: Could you write out an example formulation? How are you characterizing the compact set? Is it box-constrained, or are there other constraints? My gut feeling with your current description is that you'd be better off minimizing the square of the norm (which is differentiable) rather than the norm itself (which is not differentiable).

Comment: I think he's looking for the unconstrained minimum, and the part about it being in a compact set is just to help assure us that the minimum actually exists.

Comment: Also, is the induced 2-norm really important, or would the Frobenius norm suffice? Dealing with differentiable matrix functions becomes so much easier when using the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thanks for your responses; I will try to write up an example formulation later if I can. It is not so easy to create explicit examples that aren't trivial.

@NickAlger, I agree that using the Frobenius norm would be nice. In fact, I'm currently using Newton's method to minimize the Frobenius norm in order to compute a good initial vector for the quasi-Newton method for the 2-norm minimization.

Comment: One problem that may occur is that the minimizer is at a corner, i.e., at a point where the maximal singular value crosses with the second largest singular value, so it has multiplicity greater 1 at that point. Thus the assumptions of smooth optimization fail, there may be no gradient to be set to zero. One has to follow a handful of the largest singular values and observe their clustering to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be exactly the problem addressed in the following paper. Just recast the problem of minimizing $||A||_2$ into a problem of minimizing the maximum eigenvalue of $A^T A$.

> Overton, Michael L., and Robert S. Womersley. "Second derivatives for optimizing eigenvalues of symmetric matrices." SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 16.3 (1995): 697-718.  http://ftp.cs.nyu.edu/cs/faculty/overton/papers/pdffiles/eighess.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I had already been pointed to some of Overton's works, but I appreciate your help. I had not looked at that specific paper.